# Array textboxes with onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<INPUT name="Qty[]" id="Qty[]" type="text" class="south" />
<INPUT name="Amount[]" id="Amount[]" type="text" class="south"/>
<INPUT name="TotalAmount[]" id="TotalAmount[]" type="text" class="south" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Here i have problem with my code that i need to calculate multiply the first two textboxes. and that result will be appear into the last one, i mean third textbox as TotalAmount. Could you help me? here three textboxes appeared in single row with add button. when i submit the add button new created with three boxes again. I need to finish it in jquery of java script. please help me guys

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the array-declaration, you're not using the the input fields as arrays. they are single values.

```
<INPUT name="Qty" id="Qty" type="text" class="south" />
<INPUT name="Amount" id="Amount" type="text" class="south"/>
<INPUT name="TotalAmount" id="TotalAmount" type="text" class="south" disabled="disabled"/>
```

And the jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  qty = $("#Qty").val();
  amount = $("Amount").val();
  $("#Qty, #Amount").keyup(function(){
    $("#TotalAmount").val((qty)*(amount)); 

  });
});
```

Comment: The array declarations may be necessary if the back-end is PHP

Answer (score 0):

Here is your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    var $quantity = $('#Qty\\[\\]'),
        $amount = $('#Amount\\[\\]'),
        $total = $('#TotalAmount\\[\\]'),
        quantity,
        amount;   
    $($quantity.add($amount)).keyup(function () {
        quantity = Number($quantity.val().replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, ''));
        amount = Number($amount.val().replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, ''));

        $total.val(quantity * amount);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE** Changed to keep the DOM ids the same in case they have to be that way. For an unmentioned reason as mentioned by @Ken Keenan.